# Set theory by Julia Robinson

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, book-recommendation, online-resources

I used to have a set theory textbook downloaded free from the internet. I lost my laptop in the airport of a city in Eastern Europe, and it was not found (or perhaps “not found”) by the airport security. I now try to rediscover the file. I remember the author was a female mathematician from Berkeley. From an internet search I believe that it might have been Julia Robinson, but I still can’t find the book.

It had a fair number of exercises and I believe it covered Gödel’s incompleteness theorem. 
I would be grateful for help to find the book.

Comment: Wikipedia lists no publications of a book by Julia Robinson, but that might be incomplete.

Comment: I do not recall Julia Robinson writing a set theory book. Perhaps you are thinking of Judith Roitman? (Her textbook should be downloadable from her page, though she is not at Berkeley.)

Comment: Thank you, it was Roitman. Introduction to Modern Set Theory. Excellent.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the book "Introduction to Modern Set Theory" located [here](http://www.math.ku.edu/~roitman/SetTheory.pdf) by Judith Roitman. Might that be the book you're thinking of?

Comment: Yes it was. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you google the title of your questions, one of the links shown is to the collected works of Julia Robinson, and google books does indeed show you a discussion of Godel's incompleteness theorem on one of the [pages](http://books.google.com/books?id=_33D84OENIAC&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=Set+theory+by+Julia+Robinson&source=bl&ots=Uec-HgBop5&sig=7PaK0tWxMVLv2nrNxP7Rk_c7EqM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NhVUVMqSA6PlsATWg4GQDQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Set%20theory%20by%20Julia%20Robinson&f=false)

Comment: Thanks. This is also interesting but I was wrong about Robinson. It was Roitman all along. I am deeply impressed by all the brilliant females from Berkeley.

Comment: Yes I have seen the set theory book by Roitman (and I have seen the author a few times at conferences) but I do not have the book, and could not remember if it had a section about Goedel's theorem. I should point out Mary Ellen Rudin (who passed away a couple of years ago) kind of unique book Lectures on set theoretic topology (1975), not quite the same area, but my advisor used it when I was a student.